# SEO of asp.net meta tags

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

Simply wondering if any SEO specialists out there know if Google or other search providers index meta differently because of the id generated by asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, they will ignore meta tags and do whatever they please.

As [stevemegson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25028/stevemegson) notes, the description meta tag is useful for providing your own description to display on the SERP (no guarantees it will be used).

Heres a great quote from the [Wiki page for Meta_Tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_tag#The_description_attribute):

> Major search engine robots are more
>   likely to quantify such extant factors
>   as the volume of incoming links from
>   related websites, quantity and quality
>   of content, technical precision of
>   source code, spelling, functional v.
>   broken hyperlinks, volume and
>   consistency of searches and/or viewer
>   traffic, time within website, page
>   views, revisits, click-throughs,
>   technical user-features, uniqueness,
>   redundancy, relevance, advertising
>   revenue yield, freshness, geography,
>   language and other intrinsic
>   characteristics.

Comment: +1 for no, though saying they ignore meta tags is a bit harsh - description is still rather useful to suggest a snippet to appear on results pages